# SQL Join Two Queries Without Unique Relation

Tags: sql

I have some tables setup and linked in a system like so:

**Products**

- ActualID PK
- ProductID
- ItemID

**Items**

- ItemID PK
- DataID

**ItemsDataOne**

- DataID PK
- Value (value I need)

**ItemsDataTwo**

- DataID PK
- Value (value I need)

I'm having a problem with the following select where there are ProductIDs with more then one instance of themselves:

```
select names.ProductID, names.Name, descriptions.Desc
from 
    (select Products.ProductID, ItemsDataOne.Value as Name
    from Products
    inner join Items on Items.ItemI = Product.ItemID
    inner join ItemsDataOne ON ItemsDataOne.DataID = Items.DataID) as names
inner join
    (select Products.ProductID, ItemsDataTwo.Value as Desc
    from Products
    inner join Items on Items.ItemI = Product.ItemID
    inner join ItemsDataTwo ON ItemsDataTwo.DataID = Items.DataID) as descriptions
on names.ProductID = descriptions.ProductID
```

Which returns duplicates like this:

Actual Result

```
ProductID    Name    Description
01           "One"   "Description One"
01           "Two"   "Description One"
01           "One"   "Description Two"
01           "Two"   "Description Two"
```

What I want

```
ProductID    Name    Description
01           "One"   "Description One"
01           "Two"   "Description Two"
```

Comment: can you post data which produced such result?

Comment: `ItemsDataOne` and `ItemsDataTwo`are 2 tables? `DataID ` columns aren't foreign keys related to items tables?

Comment: Yeah ItemsDataOne and ItemsDataTwoare are two separate tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done more simply without subselects:

```
select Products.ProductID, ItemsDataOne.Value, ItemsDataTwo.Value
from Products
inner join Items on Items.ItemID = Product.ItemID
inner join ItemsDataOne ON ItemsDataOne.DataID = Items.DataID
inner join ItemsDataTwo ON ItemsDataTwo.DataID = Items.DataID
```

(You were missing the relation between ItemsDataOne and ItemsDataTwo - they need to have the same DataID.)

Comment: Also add `GROUP BY Products.ProductID, ItemsDataOne.Value, ItemsDataTwo.Value` perhaps. At least a mention of it would be good

Comment: @Mackan why group by? distinct would have the same effect.

Comment: @PavelGatnar Yes, same thing (i.e. same result). I'm just defaulting to group by _too_ often ;) Neither is present here though

Comment: Nevermind, my description of the table structure is a bit off. This is right for the question asked though!